# Imagemagick masking

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

I have an image that looks like this:

[image]

However, the background of this image is white, NOT transparent.

I was wondering if there was a way, that I could use this mask and make the white background of the original image transparent:

[image]

I think I might need to use something from here, but I can't find out what it is: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/

I am using Imagemagick on command line. (Which is what the examples use on http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/)

*Sorry for not being able to provide the URLs/images directly, I currently do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the section [Masking Simple Backgrounds (floodfill)](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#floodfill) on the ImageMagick page you mentioned. The examples there should do exactly what you want. But as that page says, the resulting image won't look very good on a dark background.